# Line pieces in Tee chart lite XE5

Tags: line, teechart, series

I'm trying to create this type of graph in Delphi XE5 with teechart lite:

[image]

So I have points (x1,y1),(x2,y2), ....,(xk,yk).

Points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) form line piece no. 1.

The second line piece is (x3,y3), (x4,y4) and so on. Note that (x2,y2) is different than (x3,y3) they are not the same point.

With the tee chart lite is it possible to create such a graph in XE5?

Comment: I tried using the standard Tfastlineseries and then making one line in the middle invisible but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different options to do this with TeeChart.

- **One series and null points.** You can add a null point after each segment so the lines in your series won't be connected. Ie:

  ```
  uses Series;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

    procedure AddSegment(Series: TChartSeries; X0, Y0, X1, Y1: Double);
    begin
      Series.AddXY(X0, Y0);
      Series.AddXY(X1, Y1);
      Series.AddNullXY(X1, Y1);
    end;

  var fastLine1: TFastLineSeries;
  begin
    Chart1.View3D:=false;

    fastLine1:=Chart1.AddSeries(TFastLineSeries) as TFastLineSeries;
    fastLine1.TreatNulls:=tnDontPaint;

    AddSegment(fastLine1, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    AddSegment(fastLine1, 2, 1, 3, 0);
    AddSegment(fastLine1, 4, 2, 5, 3);
  end;
  ```
- **Multiple series.**. You can have a series for each segment. Ie:

  ```
  uses Series;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

    procedure AddSegment(Chart: TChart; X0, Y0, X1, Y1: Double);
    begin
      with Chart.AddSeries(TFastLineSeries) do
      begin
        AddXY(X0, Y0);
        AddXY(X1, Y1);

        Color:=Chart[0].Color;
      end;
    end;

  begin
    Chart1.View3D:=false;

    AddSegment(Chart1, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    AddSegment(Chart1, 2, 1, 3, 0);
    AddSegment(Chart1, 4, 2, 5, 3);
  end;
  ```
- **A DrawLineTool.** This tool allows you to draw line segments directly with the mouse, or add them by code. Ie:

  ```
  uses Series, TeeTools;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

    procedure AddSegment(tool: TDrawLineTool; X0, Y0, X1, Y1: Double);
    begin
      tool.Lines.AddLine(X0, Y0, X1, Y1);
    end;

  var drawLineTool1: TDrawLineTool;
  begin
    Chart1.View3D:=false;

    Chart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(0, 5);
    Chart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(0, 3);
    Chart1.AddSeries(TFastLineSeries);

    drawLineTool1:=Chart1.Tools.Add(TDrawLineTool) as TDrawLineTool;
    AddSegment(drawLineTool1, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    AddSegment(drawLineTool1, 2, 1, 3, 0);
    AddSegment(drawLineTool1, 4, 2, 5, 3);
  end;
  ```